# Open image in new tab in spfx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react, reactjs

I want to open image in new tab if some one click on legend "Click here".

```
<p className="legends"><FieldUrlRenderer text={'Click here'} url={imageList.Image ? imageList.Image["Url"] :''} className="Videolegends"  /></p>
```

Currently it is opening in same window if I click on link.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908022/open-image-in-new-window). It opens image in new window. Or something like `window.open(image.src, '_blank');`

Comment: Or you can try adding your image somewhere in SharePoint library/picture gallery, Add `a` tag(hyperlink) with `target="_blank` attribute and give image path in `href` attribute.

Comment: i have added a code which i am trying

Comment: thanks this worked i changed it accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following workarounds:

1. **Using [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)**:

```
    window.open(imageUrl, '_blank');
```

2. **Using Anchor tag / hyperlink**:

   - Add your image somewhere in SharePoint library/picture gallery
   - Add anchor tag (hyperlink) with `target="_blank` attribute and give image path in `href` attribute.

Comment: Yes tried same and its working by using anchor tag

Comment: Great. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.